# Why any postcss nesting plugins doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss

(4:3) Nested CSS was detected, but CSS nesting has not been configured correctly.
Please enable a CSS nesting plugin *before* Tailwind in your configuration.
See how here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting

My postcss.config.js file:

```
  plugins: [
    "postcss-import",
    "tailwindcss/nesting",
    "tailwindcss",
    "autoprefixer",
  ],
};
```

I tried to write it down like this:

```
  plugins: {
    "postcss-import": {},
    "tailwindcss/nesting": {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

and like this:

```
  plugins: [
    require("postcss-import"),
    require("tailwindcss/nesting"),
    require("tailwindcss"),
    require("autoprefixer"),
  ],
};
```

Github repo with this project: https://github.com/frkam/test-app

When I try to use nesting, i get this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0COC.png)

Comment: Are you using Create React App, version 5? There are some known issues with PostCSS support, which is now included along with Tailwind, and CRA 5 does not allow overrides using `postcss.config.js`. See: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11717#issuecomment-992854266

Comment: @EdLucas yes, i use CRA5. As I understand it, the solution to this problem may be to roll back to a previous version or use a different preprocessor. Thanks.

Comment: There's an open PR to fix this, which will hopefully be implemented. You can follow the issue here: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/7049

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ed Lucas mentioned above CRA5 does not allow to override postcss.config
But at the moment you can use something like [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco)

An Example you can find in Felipe Zavan [comment](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/issues/378#issuecomment-1044775670)

This works for me. So I hope it will be helpful :)

My craco.config

```
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      loaderOptions: (postcssLoaderOptions) => {
        postcssLoaderOptions.postcssOptions.plugins = [
          require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
          require('tailwindcss'),
          require('postcss-mixins'),
          'postcss-flexbugs-fixes',
          [
            'postcss-preset-env',
            {
              autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: 'no-2009',
              },
              stage: 0,
            },
          ],
        ]

        return postcssLoaderOptions
      },
    },
  },
}
```